# assigning undefined php variable to jquery variable causes script to stop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following document ready function

```
        $(document).ready(function(){

                        var id = <?php echo "" ?>;
                        alert('boo');
                        if(id!=0){
            $('#quoteoutput').load('getorder.php?order=' + id, function () {})
                        }});
```

The script stops executing as i passed an empty variable to var id through PHP and the boo alert message is not returned

If i echo a value than it is fine.
Can someone tell me why this is as i have a php variable `<?php echo "$id" ?>;`that is sometimes empty and this causes a problem running this kind of script. If you could also advise of the best solution for this. At the moment i have declared in php a non empty var 0

```
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
$id=$_GET['id'];
}
else{
$id="0";
}
```

but if there is a better workaround or solution please let me know.

Thanks

Rehan Miah

Answer (score 0):

You will need here quotes before you open the tag:

```
var id = "<?php echo "" ?>";
```

---

Because when PHP executes it, it would return

```
var id = ;
```

when you use no quotes

## edit

By the way, you can read GET Parameters with Javascript too.
Have a look at here

```
function GetURLParameter(sParam)
{
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
        {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}​
```

With calling

```
var id = GetUrlParameter("id");
```

you have stored the get parameter in your var

Comment: I cant just write var id = ""; because it is a variable that can be empty sometimes as mentioned in the whole post

Comment: problem is not fully resolved still have problem passing php GET request variable                    var id = "<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>";

Answer (score 0):

Best Approach will be using from json_encode method

```
var id = <?php echo json_encode($id); ?>;
```

Comment: Thanks saved unnecessary coding

Comment: if you confirm that the variable is defined it's works. in which state you cant get result?

Comment: In my case $id will always not be assigned a variable as it get its variable from $_get which will always not be defined. I am not sure why this worked in the first place and stopped working.

Comment: I just understood what you meant by I'd defined $id is not just going to be defined as blank but mainly from URL get which sometimes might not exist.

Comment: when you use get parameters you have to eventually do a validation on parameter that means the if else should be in code to guarantee the existence  of variable.